# Change NaT to blank in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (`df`) that looks like:

```
        DATES
0         NaT
1  01/08/2003
2         NaT
3         NaT
4  04/08/2003
5         NaT
6  30/06/2003
7  01/03/2004
8  18/05/2003
9         NaT
10        NaT
11 31/10/2003
12        NaT
13        NaT
```

I am struggling to find out how I transform the data-frame to remove the `NaT` values so the final output looks like

```
        DATES
0         
1  01/08/2003
2         
3         
4  04/08/2003
5         
6  30/06/2003
7  01/03/2004
8  18/05/2003
9         
10        
11 31/10/2003
12        
13
```

I have tried :

```
df["DATES"].fillna("", inplace = True)
```

but with no success.

For information the column is in a datatime format set with

```
df["DATES"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DATES"],errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Is the column in datetime format?

Comment: `df.replace({pd.NaT: ''}, inplace=True)`?

Comment: By doing `dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')` you're casting to string again. Hence the error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is problem `NaT` are strings, so need:

```
df["DATES"] = df["DATES"].replace('NaT', '')
```

Comment: does not work when column type is *time. so setting to "" results in NaT since "" is not a time

Comment: @SonicSoul - Sure, first need `df["DATES"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DATES"],errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')` and then `df["DATES"] = df["DATES"].replace('NaT', '')`

Answer (score 1):

`df.fillna()` works on numpy.NaN values. Your "Nat" are probably strings. So you can do following,

if you want to use `fillna()`

```
df["DATES"].replace("NaT",np.NaN, inplace=True)
df.fillna("", inplace=True)
```

Else, you can just replace with your desired string

```
df["DATES"].replace("NaT","", inplace=True)
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you do not have enough reputation to comment yet, it does not mean that you should use answer as comments.

Comment: In that case you should make sure to provide an actual answer, which includes some code, especially given that your answer solves OPs issue

Comment: (It does not solve OPs issue - OP explicitly stated that their column is datetime. If they are wrong, that's another issue to solve)

Answer (score 0):

Convert column to object and then use Series.where:

```
df['Dates'] = df['Dates'].astype(object).where(df['Date'].notnull(),np.nan)
```

Or whatever you want np.nan to be

Answer (score 0):

Your conversion to `datetime` did not work properly on the `NaT`s.

You can check this before calling the `fillna` by printing out `df['DATES'][0]` and seeing that you get a `'NaT'` (string) and not `NaT` (your wanted format)

Instead, use (for example): `df['DATES'] = df['DATES'].apply(pd.Timestamp)`

This example worked for me as is, but notice that it's not `datetime` but rather `pd.Timestamp` (it's another time format, but it's an easy one to use). You do not need to specify your time format with this, your current format is understood by `pd.Timestamp`.